# Pygame: Error with placing multiple objects :(

Tags: python, pygame

So I started programming a little block placing game in Python/Pygame.
I wrote up the code, and in theory it looked perfect.. It should be able to place multiple blocks at the press of the mouse. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0) 
blocklistDIRT=[]
class block(object):

    sprite = None

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        if not block.sprite:
            block.sprite = pygame.image.load("dirt.png").convert_alpha()
        self.rect = block.sprite.get_rect(top=y, left=x)

blocklist = []    
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            blocklist.append(block(mse[0],mse[1])) 
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    for block in blocklist:
        screen.blit(block.sprite, block.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

And every time I go to place a second block.. I get this error:

Traceback (most recent call last):   File
"C:\Users\samis_000\Desktop\blockgame.pyw", line 20, in 
blocklist.append(block(mse[0],mse[1])) TypeError: 'block' object is not callable

Someone tell me what I am doing wrong :(

Comment: inside your block.__init__, replace all occurencies of block. with self. :D

Comment: To avoid multiple memory allocation for the same sprite, you can use a factory class to retrieve sprite data. By using a generic factory structure, you can avoid coding the same control (if clause in __init__) for every game entity you have.

Comment: Changed them all to self, that didn't work either. Still the same error! And @diegoperini explain your method further please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All declarations of classes should be capitalized by convention. In addition, when you call the constructor for a class, the name should match the capitalized name for the class. Here is one version of your code that should work:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,480),0) 
blocklistDIRT=[]
class Block(object):

    sprite = pygame.image.load("dirt.png").convert_alpha()

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.rect = block.sprite.get_rect(top=y, left=x)

blocklist = []    
while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONUP:
            mse=pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            blocklist.append(Block(mse[0],mse[1])) 
        if event.type == QUIT:
            exit()
    for block in blocklist:
        screen.blit(block.sprite, block.rect)
    pygame.display.update()
```

See how in the code, the capitalized words are highlighted in blue? That's because they are class names, which are different from your *instance* names.

I also took the liberty of removing that strange logic you had in your Block class declaration for loading an image.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I had to replace "block.sprite.get_rect" with "self.sprite.get_rect" but it worked!!

Comment: @Sam woops, didn't even see that. :) Nice catch.

Comment: Lol. Thanks for your help. I'm a tad new to Pygame.

Answer (score 1):

If you capitalize your block class (e.g. `class Block(object)`) you will probably resolve this issue.  It's because this code

```
for block in blocklist:
    screen.blit(block.sprite, block.rect)
```

also uses the lowercase `block`, making future calls to `block` get confused about whether you're talking about creating a new block with the block class (which you have lowercase) or the `block` you've (re)defined in the loop.

Also, I agree with Samuele's comment, you should use `self` inside your class wherever it's appropriate, but I can't tell from your snippet whether that too will cause issues.

Comment: Let me give it a try! Thanks :)

Comment: It is common practice to capilatize class names like 'ThisIsMyNewAwesomeClass'.

Comment: Capitalized all uses of 'block' and I still got the error :( Any more suggestions?

Comment: Not all uses of `block`, just uses where you're talking about creating a new `block`.  Also, if you can add your code in an edit underneath your current post, it'd be helpful to see where you're at

Comment: @SamTubb, did you edit your post?  I can't see any additional code

Comment: Yeah I did. It says "Will be visible when viewed by peers" I don't know what that means..

Comment: @jedwards Want me to post it somewhere else?